# How to use a mask/validation on textbox in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, material-design-in-xaml

I'm building a project using WPF with Material Design in XAML. The objetive is to do a valiation or a mask for a textbox. I can't use other extensions that provides a Mask in Textbox because the Style will be different from the Material Design TextBox.

Simple example of code:

`<TextBox x:Name="CEPTextBox" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignTextBox}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top">`

What needs to be done: a mask for a validation like 00000-000 (accepting values like 12345-789). What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use existing masked textbox and overwrite the style to match your style, or write/copy your own.

This
https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/MaskedTextBox
works quite nice and it's not hard to redefine the style.
You can also look at the source
https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/blob/master/ExtendedWPFToolkitSolution/Src/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit/MaskedTextBox/Implementation/MaskedTextBox.cs
and try to implement your own.

However, it's the wrong way to go, because restyling controls is one of WPF strengths.

EDIT: Simple example

To redefine style in a single view, try something like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="PA.Views.MainView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
        >
<UserControl.Resources>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type xctk:MaskedTextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkRed"/>
</Style>    
</UserControl.Resources>
   
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <xctk:MaskedTextBox />
</Grid>
```

To redefine style everywhere, create a global resource dictionary (for example, in directory Themes/Generic.xaml). Add something like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
                >

<Style TargetType="{x:Type xctk:MaskedTextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkRed"/>
</Style>
```

and reference this dictionary in App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Themes/Generic.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

If you already have a style for a TextBox, you can just apply this style to the MaskedTextBox

Comment: Do you have any link or code that can help me to redefine the style? I'm still new with xaml and WPF

Comment: There are a lots of articles and code samples around. I have added a simple example in the answer.